# How to build Orbeon Forms in Professional Edition mode?

Tags: build, xhtml, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

I have downloaded Orbeon source code from the following link, https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Contributors-~-Building-Orbeon-Forms#from-the-command-line. After downloading the distribution, I have unzip the distribution and created the build through command line.

By default It is created the build for Community Edition. How do I create a build for Professional Edition? Where do I need to change the properties/configuration to build the Orbeon in Professional mode?

Some documentation stated that the source code for both versions will be same.But while building It will build for Community Edition. Is there any tutorials/suggestions that how to build in Professional Edition Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbeon does not provide public instructions or code to build Orbeon Forms PE, which is a commercial, supported build of the product.

This said, at this time, the source code is the same between CE and PE with the exception of the `build.xml` file. (Note that in the future some PE features might be not be present in the public code base.)

So you could tweak `build.xml` to enable PE features and tweak the source code to disable license checking, no problem with that. The idea is just that we want to ensure that something called "PE" in fact comes from Orbeon.